# Posting a page to an iframe causing pop-up blocker to prevent the post action

Tags: jquery, post, iframe, popup

I'm trying to get a page to load in an Iframe from a post with the POST variables sent along with the page that will be loaded.  There is nothing that is explicitly opening a new window, but I am getting a pop-up blocked notification in FF and Chrome.  IE doesn't block the POST yet but probably will in a future update.  Listed below is the code that triggers the pop up.

```
gamePage.name = 'game_page';
setTimeout('', 100);
gamePage.onload = setTimeout("$.download(getCompletePath() +'account/SomeFile.php',  gameId='+game_Id+'&playMode=J', 'post', 'game_page')", 0);
```

and here is the $.download function:

```
jQuery.download = function(url, data, method, target){
    //url and data options required
    if( url && data ){ 
        //data can be string of parameters or array/object
        data = typeof data == 'string' ? data : jQuery.param(data);
        //split params into form inputs
        var inputs = '';
        jQuery.each(data.split('&'), function(){ 
            var pair = this.split('=');
            inputs+='<input type="hidden" name="'+ pair[0] +'" value="'+ pair[1] +'" />'; 
        });
        //send request
        jQuery('<form action="'+ url +'" method="'+ (method||'post') +'" target="' + target +'">'+inputs+'</form>')
        .appendTo('body').submit().remove();
    };
};
```

Currently we have this action being performed by GET but we are switching most if not all GET requests to POST where possible.  Any help help on how to get around the pop-up blocker when POSTing to the iframe would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am doing the same, but Chrome is working correctly; IE and Firefox are giving popup blocker errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an iFrame, use just a simple DIV.

Call jQuery.post() method, and put the response as the innerHTML of your div using jQuery.html(/*response*/) function.

Something like that:

```
$.post("urlToLoad.ext", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
.success(function(data) {
    $('#yourDivID').html(data);
});
```